# Do *Unix shells call the pipe() function when encountering the "pipe character"?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, gnu

What do *nix shells do exactly when encountering the "pipe character" in the command line?

Does the chaining of **stdout** to **stdin** involve calling the pipe() system function?

Comment: Yes, it does involve creating a FIFO pair.

Comment: Yes. The `pipe()` system call was created precisely for this use.

Comment: ...that said, we already have (far, *far* too many) "how do I implement pipes in my classroom toy shell?" questions that answer what this asks (and go beyond that to discuss implementation caveats &c).

Comment: @Duffy:  I do not want to implement my own shell.  I just want to understand whether the naming similarity between the "pipe function" and "pipe character" is coincidental or has actual meaning.

Comment: @KarolaN, granted, but given as every single "how do I implement pipelines when writing my own shell in C?" question will tell you that the answer involves correct use of `pipe()` function (or correctly managing FDs leading up to the `exec()`-family call following the `pipe()` and subsequent `fork()`), this question is a subset of those.

Comment: @Duffy:  It would if I knew, that the chain of processes created by the shell when it encounters the "pipe character" was formally called a "pipeline",  when I was asking this question. I am a *nix a newbie and I lack the proper jargon.  Terminology, which might seem obvious to savvy users like you, is not so obvious to newbies. BTW:  Could you restore the links to the duplicate questions, which you've edited out?  ... if they elaborate on that issue.

Comment: Literally, the first occurrence of the string "pipe" in the `bash` man page is a section entitled "Pipelines".